# Crash while accessing specific index of vector in class

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am currently trying to make a 2d vector representing pixels.
The problem is that when I try to set a value at a specific index the program crash.
The compilation is good.
Here is the .h :

```
#include "../include/graphics.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace rgb_matrix;

class Viewport
{
public:
    Viewport(std::string id,int xMn,int yMn,int xMx,int yMx,Canvas *c)
    {
        canvas_=c;
        _id = id;
        _x = xMn;
        _y = yMn;
        width=xMx-xMn;
        height=yMx-yMn;

    }

    void SetPixel(int x_vport,int y_vport,rgb_matrix::Color c);
    int getXMax(){
        return _x + height;
    }
    int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }
    int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    int getX(){
        return _x;
    }
    void clear();
    std::string getId(){return _id;}
    void show();
    void fill(int r,int g,int b);
private :
    Canvas *canvas_;
    int width,height;
    int _x,_y;
    std::string _id;
    std::vector<std::vector<rgb_matrix::Color> > colors;
};
```

The weird point is that I can access to the values into the .h but not into the .cpp :

```
void Viewport::SetPixel(int x, int y, rgb_matrix::Color c) {
    if(x>=0 && y>= 0 && x< width && y < height) {//if in rectangle
        colors.at(x).at(y) = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put this into a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Based on the code you've shown the `colors` vector is always empty so trying to access anything in it will be out of range.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can access to the values into the .h but not into the .cpp"? Do you mean that`SetPixel` actually works if you define it in the header (this is very hard to believe) or something else?

Comment: Seems colors is not initialized, this statement `colors.at(x).at(y) = c;` is expected to crash because of access violation.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** how you fill values in the vector:

```
void Viewport::SetPixel(int x, int y, rgb_matrix::Color c) {
    if(x>=0 && y>= 0 && x< width && y < height) {//if in rectangle
        colors.at(x).at(y) = c;
    }
}
```

Before you visit an element of the vector `colors.at(x)` you must assure that the size of the vector `colors.size()` is bigger than `x`. So, maybe you call `colors.resize()` somewhere in other place, before filling vector with values.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is intended, that's an exception thrown due to the out-of-bounds access.

I would question the choice of the data structure:

- std::vector<rgb_matrix::Color> can be chosen if you need the continuous block of memory (just remember to either resize it or construct it with width*height parameter =)
- vector of vectors implies a dense nonrectangular structure - normally it's used for something like triangle matrices to save the memory.
- `using x = unsigned; using y = unsigned;vector::<std::tuple<x, y, rgb::matrix::Color>`  can be used for a sparse structure with a few pixels in random places.

Also `x>=0 && y>= 0` can be avoided if you switch to `unsigned` instead of `int`=)